# Why are there different ways to write href links to HTML files when using <a> tags?

Tags: html

Why do HTML links sometimes add `./`  before HTML file destination, and sometimes not?

Example:

```
<a href="./contact.html">Contact Us</a> 
        //compared to
<a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
```

Coding language: HTML 
Skill level: Beginner 
Editor: Visual Studio Code 
OS: Windows 7

Comment: imagine you are in "http://www.somwhere.com/someLink" if you use ./contact.html it refers to "http://www.somwhere.com/someLink/contact.html" but case using "contact.html" link will refer to "http://www.somwhere.com/contact.html"

Comment: @X-_-FARZA_D-_-X That is not the case, both links will stay in the "current directory", which would be `http://somwhere.com/`.